# Set only lower limits in ggplot2 scale_x_datetime(limits)

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, scale

I have a DB that reads a value every 5 minutes. In order to display the data, I have a Shiny App that plots it each time you connect to it. I recently added a daterangeinput, in order to select the data to plot.

The problem is when I plot the data of the same day. The display is small (because it's representing until the same night althought data doesn't exist yet) while using `scale_x_datetime(limits)`. Here's an example:

[image]

I don't mind the lower limits, as they will always exist. I would like to set the lower limits and let the upper limit be free (and the last value to appear in the right border of the plot).

I tried setting the second limit to `NULL` or not even putting it but it throws me errors.

Here's the code:

```
ggplot(query, aes(x=DateTime, y=Freq, group=1)) + 
  geom_line() +
  labs(x="Time", y="Freq") +
  ggtitle("PLOT") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks= pretty_breaks()) +
  scale_x_datetime(limits = as.POSIXct(input$rangeDate))
```

The data frame `query` looks like this, for example:

```
             DateTime       Freq
1 2015-09-11 09:22:57         10
2 2015-09-11 09:27:57         10
3 2015-09-11 09:32:57         11
```

Maybe the solution can be doing this in other way. I will higly appreciate your comments and answers.

Thanks

Comment: Care to make your code [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? I doubt many SO users have the R object `query` in their R environments.

Comment: Set the second limit to `NA`, not `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As aosmith said,

> You can't omit the upper limit, but you can use NA for one of the limits that you want automatically calculated. See the help page for ggplot2::ylim

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`limits` needs a vector of length two to work, so omitting the upper limit won't work.
Also, as I see it, `rangeDate` is not an element of your data.frame `query` which ggplot refers to.
Maybe something like

`... + scale_x_datetime(data=input, limits=c(min(rangeDate), max(rangeDate))`

will work.

EDIT:

Alternatively, put your variable `rangeDate` in the data.frame you use in `ggplot()`.

Comment: You can't omit the upper limit, but you can use `NA` for one of the limits that you want automatically calculated.  See the help page for `ggplot2::ylim`.